# Get cells in a row Excel Addin Nodejs Api

Tags: excel, api, office-js, add-in, excel-addins

The problem is that when we get full range (e.g., `=SUM(A:A)` gives `A:A` as precedent) as precedents we need to check the cells within this range. But can we get only the actual populated cells in a row/col?

Right now we call api to get precedents for each cell. Excel throws error for non populated cells but we need to reduce the api calls if we want to take the add-in to the same performance level as the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in `getSpecialCellsOrNullObject` api.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges-special-cells

```
const range = excelSheet.getRange("A:A");
const numberCells = range.getSpecialCellsOrNullObject(Excel.SpecialCellType.constants, Excel.SpecialCellValueType.numbers);
```